# Windows installation detectes hard drive, but bios does not

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

Some days ago my computer started to be unstable. It only started when "he wanted".

Today it stopped to initialize and BIOS can't recognize my sata hard-drives.

When I load Windows 7 installation, I can see my hard drives, check files, do a chkdsk and everything (all seems to be fine). But it stills not loading nor showing on BIOS.

What could I do?

Comment: check this way, Go to the bios setting and reset that to default setting!

Comment: Already have tried that...I have resetted it sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

chkdsk /B

It will check for bad sectors also.  Once chkdsk /B deals with the bad sectors try windows repair to fix windows.

Comment: I have tried, but didn't worked. I have also tried "chkdsk /f /r".

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

1. Turn Off your system
2. Open your case
3. like picture looking for SATA ports (some sata cables are red)
4. unplug your sata wire and plug to another sata port
5. turn on your system and check it out !

[image]

Comment: Already tried that...I have even a PCI board with sata ports where I plugged it into. As said, HDs are recognized, but only at Windows installation.